# How do I keep my text and my link on the same line in html

Tags: html

Here is my code

**CODE** 
http://puu.sh/cSfQh/298a44fb3b.png

But it ends up like this
http://puu.sh/cSfEk/857e4a15a8.png
I would like them to be on the same line.

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not a picture of your code.

Comment: i could not for some reason, it just wasn't working. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with `display: inline-block;`. Make sure you put it in the the `<h4 >` tag because that's the (block) element that's causing a new line to be created.

e.g.,

```
<small>Posted</small><h4 style="display:inline"><a href="">Our</a></h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, try adding:

```
display: inline-block;
```

in CSS. You can also use `style="display: inline-block;"` directly in the HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css and it should work:

```
small {
    float: left;
    // or
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css it should do the rtrick

```
small ,h4 {
    display: inline;
}
```

OR

```
small , h4 {
    display: inline !important;
}
```